# Why is this c++ program not working?

Tags: c++

Write program to have base class
Number
and two derived classes:
Square and Cube
.
You will calculate the square number (a*a
) and
cube of the number (a*a*a)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h> 
using namespace std;
class Number 
{
protected:
    int a ;
    int y;
public: 
    a*a = y;
    a*a*a=y 
};
 class Square : Number 
{
    int a , y;
public:
     (a*a) = y;
};

class Cube : Number
{
    int a, y;
public:
    (a*a*a) = y;
};
int main()
{
    int a;
    cout << "Enter number "<< endl;
    cin >> a >>endl ; 
    cout << " the Square of this number is : " << (a*a); 
    cout << "Enter number ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << " the cube of this number is : " << (a*a*a);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Because it isn't even remotely valid C++ code as currently written?

Comment: a*a=y? what you want to do?

Comment: you should start with a "hello world" program that works, and build on top of that; not trying to code everything and then trying to get it working...

Answer (score 4):

```
public: 
  a*a = y;
  a*a*a=y
```

is not a function. The

```
private:
protected:
public:
```

sections define how a function or variable can be seen outside of the class. You cannot do any assignment within them: you need to put assignments into a function, such as a function like `int multiply()` or similar:

```
class Number 
{
protected:
    int a ;
    int y;
public: 
    int squared(int a);
    int cubed(int a);
};

int Number::squared(int a) {
    y = a * a;
    return y;
}

int Number::cubed(int a) {
    y = a * a * a;
    return y;
}
```

Your compiler errors are coming from the fact that you're doing `(a*a) = y`, which is

1. Outside of a function, and
2. Incorrectly formatted to assign the value of `(a*a)` to `y`. You need `y = (a*a)` instead.